Is there any alternative to dot while calling sub-classes
Recently I started Minecraft modding and I came up with an idea to make code cleaner a bit. I made some mods for other games, but they were in Lua (Forts especially).
I wanted to ask if there is an option to call sub-class using [] or something else. Here is an example of what I want to achieve
ModItems.rock.get(); // current state

I want to replace .rock with something like:
ModItems[itemName].get();

Is there any way to do that?
I tried searching everywhere, but I couldn't find anything or how to name it. If there's any simple solution please show it.

No, there is not.

soo how can i achieve this effect?

You can't achieve this effect in Java.

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with subclasses. It looks more like rock is a (static?) field of ModItems.

"so how can I achieve this effect?"  I think you are asking the wrong question.  It sounds like you want to use objects as an index into a data structure.
